# Get text value from Flutter Widget using Appium Flutter Driver

Tags: python, flutter, appium, python-appium

I want to use Appium under Python with the Appium Flutter driver to test my Flutter application. Some things are already working, but I have a problem with the text widgets.

I can locate a text element using the semanticsLable (see code), but then it is not possible to read the text value from the FlutterElement. Am I doing something wrong here or does it just not work this way?

Flutter code:

```
const Text("Text with semanticsLable", semanticsLabel: "text_semantic_lable"),
```

Python code:

```
driver = Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723',
                {'platformName': 'android',
                 'automationName': 'flutter',
                 'platformVersion': '',
                 'deviceName': 'emulator-5554',
                 'app': '/Users/xxxx/AndroidStudioProjects/hello_world_appium/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk'
                 })

finder = FlutterFinder()
text_finder = finder.by_semantics_label("text_semantic_lable")
text_element = FlutterElement(driver, text_finder)
print(text_element.text)
```

Error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/git/hmip-regression-testing/tests/hmip_tests/solutions/IC/flutter_test.py", line 90, in <module>
    print(text_element.text)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 89, in text
    return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 403, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/appium/webdriver/errorhandler.py", line 30, in check_response
    raise wde
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/appium/webdriver/errorhandler.py", line 26, in check_response
    super().check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot execute command get_text, server reponse {
  "isError": true,
  "response": "Uncaught extension error while executing get_text: Unsupported operation: Type Semantics is currently not supported by getText\n#0      CommandHandlerFactory._getText (package:flutter_driver/src/common/handler_factory.dart:430:7)\n<asynchronous suspension>\n#1      FlutterDriverExtension.call (package:flutter_driver/src/extension/extension.dart:372:31)\n<asynchronous suspension>\n#2      BindingBase.registerServiceExtension.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart:856:18)\n<asynchronous suspension>\n",
  "type": "_extensionType",
  "method": "ext.flutter.driver"
}
Stacktrace:
UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot execute command get_text, server reponse {
  "isError": true,
  "response": "Uncaught extension error while executing get_text: Unsupported operation: Type Semantics is currently not supported by getText\n#0      CommandHandlerFactory._getText (package:flutter_driver/src/common/handler_factory.dart:430:7)\n<asynchronous suspension>\n#1      FlutterDriverExtension.call (package:flutter_driver/src/extension/extension.dart:372:31)\n<asynchronous suspension>\n#2      BindingBase.registerServiceExtension.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart:856:18)\n<asynchronous suspension>\n",
  "type": "_extensionType",
  "method": "ext.flutter.driver"
}
    at getResponseForW3CError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:1067:9)
    at asyncHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/@appium/base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:476:57)
```